# copy and paste in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium I am trying to copy something from one page to another, the page that I copy off of already has it so if you just click on the text once it copies automatically but it is not copying anything I am not sure why

```
chrome_driver = '/Applications/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
driver.get('https://tempail.com/en/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="eposta_adres"]').click()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_first_name"]').send_keys('Scott')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_email"]').click()
act.key_down(Keys.META).send_key("COMMAND + v").key_up(Keys.META).perform()
```

Comment: your `"COMMAND + v"` is only a string, not command `COMMAND + v`. Maybe you should use `.key_down(Keys.META).key_down(Keys.V)` or something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my `Linux` in `Firefox` and `Chrome` works

```
item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v")
```

Like

```
item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_email"]')

item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v")
```

---

I tried to test it with your code but you use `xpath` which I can't find on `Instagam`

So I tested with field `Search...` on current page

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://tempail.com/en/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="eposta_adres"]').click()

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543113/copy-and-paste-in-selenium-python/')
item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="q"]')
item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v")
```

---

**BTW:** I described this long time ago in

[Selenium: How to send clipboad to field in browser — furas.pl](https://blog.furas.pl/python-selenium-send-clipboard-to-field-in-browser-gb-gb.html).

I show also how to use module [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) to work with `clipboard`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
#from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
import time
import pyperclip

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71543113/copy-and-paste-in-selenium-python/')
item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="q"]')

#text = pyperclip.paste()  # get text from cliboard
#item.clear()
#item.send_keys(text)

pyperclip.copy("Hello World")  # put text in clipboard
item.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "v")
```